# Elements of list of lists are null even though items added are not

Tags: java, javafx

Code snippet where the problem raises

```
public void saveFile() throws IOException {
        if (!wordsTable.getItems().isEmpty()) {
            TreeItem<List> selectedItem = (TreeItem<List>) filesTree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            selectedFilePath = (String) selectedItem.getValue().get(1);
            File originalFile = new File(selectedFilePath);
            File tempFile = new File(originalFile.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()+"/temp.csv");
            List<List<String>> tableData = new List<>() {};

            for (TableItem item : wordsTable.getItems()) {
                List<String> row = Arrays.asList(item.getWord(),item.getMeaning(),item.getPronunciation());
                System.out.println(row);
                tableData.add(row);
                System.out.println(tableData.get(0));
            }


            for (List<String> row : tableData) {
                System.out.println(row);
            }
            dataArrayToCSV(tempFile.getAbsolutePath(),tableData);
        } else {
            ConfirmationAlert.display("Error","Nothing to save");
        }
    }
```

I manually input some lists as rows, print the row and the item of table data which should be a list of lists. When I print the row it is as I typed it in but items of tableData are all null. So this raises a nullpointexception for each loop.

I can't seem to find why tableData's items are null even though I put the correct type of data in it.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write this: `List<List<String>> tableData = new List<>() {};`, you are supossed to create your own List implementation, but since you're not overriding any method at all, when you add items, nothing happens.

You should inititalize the tableDate with a new instance of a List implementation: `List<List<String>> tableData = new ArrayList<>();`

Since you have tagged this with JavaFX, I guess you have a dependency on javafx.base, so it'd be better to use an ObservableList: `ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> tableDate = FXCollections.observableArrayList();` Of course, that means that your first for loop should be modified accordingly: `ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList(item.getWord(), item.getMeaning(), item.getPronunciation());`

Comment: I don't know your JDK version, but you should start using var keyword, and I'd rather a List<record> instead of List<List<?>>, also migrating from File to Path would be better.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. While I agree ObservableLists are a better solution I do not intend to use this data elsewhere. So making the tableData ArrayList<List<String>> solved my problem.